# How did de Moivre originally prove his formula in the article that he published it in?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, math-history

He published a proof in the Philosophical Transactions journal in 1722. Here is an English version:

https://web.archive.org/web/20201128125816/http://cerebro.xu.edu/math/Sources/Moivre/de_%20sectione_anguli.pdf

First, he introduces two infinite polynomials and their solutions, and then goes on to describe a theorem based on those, from which if you solve for $zn and z you will get de Moivre's formula. Since the proof is rather fragmented, lacks explanations and alludes to previous calculations, I have a few questions:

1. What exactly do $A, B, C$, etc. (the "coefficients of the preceding
   terms") represent in the polynomials? Is $A = n, B = \frac{1-n^2}{2\cdot3}\cdot A,
   C = \frac{9-n^2}{4\cdot5}\cdot B$ etc.?
2. Most importantly, how does the theorem (i.e. the two equations
   containing $z$) follow from the solution of the polynomials? Where do
   those equations come from, and why do they look as they do? And what
   does $z$ represent in the equation? It appears for the first time
   there, without explanation.
3. Is $n$ assumed to be an integer, or can it be any real (or complex)
   number? What about $t$?

Comment: This might be well-suited to the HSM Stack Exchange. Anyway, it looks to me like this is an application of the formula for which he is most famous today, rather than a proof of it.